# Sharing data between users of a shared-library

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I have a shared library say foo.so which contains a function called `initialize()`.  There are multiple executables that open foo.so and each calls `initialize()`.  I would like `initialize()` to check if it has already been called by another executable and if so do nothing.  What's the best way of sharing this information between these processes?  Is there some special facility to share such information or do I need to use standard IPC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use standard IPC. Memory mapping comes to mind, but first decide whether you want initialization per user and per machine.

Comment: In this case initialize should only be called once per machine.  User information is not a factor.

Comment: @user800133: sorry, but user information *is* a factor, since permissions are required to perform IPC.

Comment: What I mean is it's not a factor how many users there are.  Initialize should only get called once.

Comment: @user800133: then every process calling into your library should run as the same user, i.e. it should be restricted to a single user or be setuid.

Answer (score 4):

Create a file /var/db/mylibname. If open() returns an error saying that the file already exists, then your library was initialized.

It'll require to add atexit() handler that will remove the file when process exits. Atexit must be initialized only if open() returns success.

**UPDATE:**

If resources must be initialized only once and if they (resources) *don't depend on the existence of any process that uses the library at the time*, then it's better to create file in /var/run directory (so that it is cleaned up after system reboot) and forget about atexit().

Comment: Ew. Who uses `atexit` any more

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Well, it depends. atexit() is a fast and dirty way, but it does its job well.

Comment: There's a possible problem with this, consider the following sequence: Process A starts up and initialises. Process B then starts and doesn't initialise because A already did it. A now exits, deleting the file. Process C now starts, checks for the existence of the file and finds it missing, so now *reinitialises*, possibly breaking B in the process if it was still using the previous initialisation from A.

Comment: @awoodland If resources must be initialized only once and if it doesn't matter whether any processes that use the library exist at the time, then atexit() shouldn't be used at all.

Comment: @DanKruchinin - my example is not "initialised only once", it's about initialised only once and not deinitialised/reinitialised until 0 users of it remain, regardless of who is the last user. (In which case you would want to reference count and probably use `rename(2)` to do it atomically

Comment: @awoodland Oh, right, probably I misinterpreted you. rename() will make it hard to know the exact file name. I think it's better to store reference count inside the file and use file locks (F_SETLKW for example) for reading and updating it. Of course it's not completely safe, for example user process can be SIGKILL'ed at the moment when it updates refcount.